# Can't add new project to existing Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, project, solution

I have a WinForms application. I see the solution file, but when I try to add new project to it and select the needed type of file, after pressing "OK" nothing happens, any ideas why?

Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.4.0

[image]

**UPDATE:**
As it turned out I couldn't even create any empty project, so I had to reinstall visual studio cause I didn't find any other solution. All works fine now.

Comment: "Nothing happens" really nice explanation. Any errors, messages anywhere? Can you add other projects?

Comment: Look in the Output WIndow. Check in all channels showing in the "Show output from" combo box - any messages relevant?

Comment: You could also try to update your VS 2017: currently last version is 15.4.5

Comment: @Reniuz really nothing, window just doesn't close and when I switch frameworks few times and press "OK" the window closes and that's all

Andrea ok, I'll try morrow

Caius Jard nothing, it stays empty